# Problems with labels in QGIS 2.10

Tags: qgis, labeling

I want to label my polygons with information, and I want the labels to be in two rows - name on row 1 och volume on row 2.
My problem is, that I get an extra "quare" at the end of row 1?
That has never happened before.

EDIT: Here is the expression I wroght:
[image]

And, it works, I just get that extra quare, like this:[image]

I use QGIS 2.10 and Windows 10, could it be because of the Windows 10? I never had this problem on Windows 8.

EDIT 2: I realize that I need to clarify my question, I have two different columns. I want the information in column 1 to be in the first row and the information from column 2 to be in the second row of the labels.
But, my expression makes the labels with an extra square at the end of row 1.

I use encoding windows-1252.

Comment: Can you write the complete label expression. What do you use as 'Wrap on character' in the labels setting for breaking the line?

Comment: I realize that my question was a bit unclear, I didn't break the line, I have two columns that I want to use on different rows in the labels.

Comment: Could it perhaps be an encoding issue? Those type of squares appear quite often if QGIS doesn't recognise certain symbols. As QGIS uses the `system` encoding by default, try changing the layer's **Data source encoding** (_Layer Properties > General_) to one such as `UTF-16`?

Comment: @Joseph I tried to change the encoding like you suggested, to UTF-16, but then the names of the columns looks like chinese? And I upgraded to QGIS 2.12.1, but the squares are still there.

Comment: @SoS - Could you perhaps share your data (or make a copy and delete most of the attributes if you have sensitive data) on a public server so that others could test it?

Answer (score 2):

The expression editor lets you wrap text from one line to the next.

I think the square may be part of a newline. In Windows, newline is two characters (`\r\n`), on Linux it's one (`\n`). What you did works on Linux (in QGIS 2.12 at least). Not sure why it would work in Windows 8 - perhaps this was in an earlier version of QGIS which may have handled newlines differently?

An easier way - as Jakob mentioned - is to choose a special character to break the text over lines. This can be any character - just make sure that it's one that won't appear in your label text. Here, I've chosen `*`. I've put this after "FASTIGHET" - that seems to be where you want the split.

```
"FASTIGHET" || '*' || CASE WHEN "Blad1_Field1" is '' THEN '' ELSE 'Volym (m3sk)' || ' ' || "Blad1_Field2" END
```

You can now use the **Formatting > Wrap on Character** setting, and your label should appear over two lines.

[image: wrap on character]